# ExtJs 5.0.1: Synchronus Ajax request in Firefox

Tags: ajax, extjs, xmlhttprequest, extjs5

In the project we have a **config singleton object**, which holds configuration fetched from the server (ServerConfig). It is defined like

```
Ext.define('SI.ServerConfig', {
    singleton: true,
    constructor: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        // Closure which holds the serverConfig after the synchronus request
        var serverConfig;

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'example.de/getConfig.php',
            method: 'POST',
            async: false,
            success: function(response){
                var responseObj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                serverConfig = responseObj.serverConfig;
            }
        });

        //definition of setter/getter function for the serverConfig closure
        this.get = function (optionName, defaultVal) {
            if (Ext.isDefined(serverConfig[optionName])){
                return serverConfig[optionName];
            }

            return defaultVal;
        };


        this.set = function (optionName, value) {
            serverConfig[optionName] = value;
        };
    }
});
```

In the constructor we have a **closure** which holds after the **synchrone Ajax request the server config object**.
We need to make a synchrone request, because the server config values are needed in various other classes to provide config bevore creation. 
With a setter and a getter function we provide access to the values defined in it.In every controller/view/model we need access to the server config, we require the singleton.

```
Ext.define('SI.view.TestView', {
    extends: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires: ['SI.ServerConfig'],

    // This fails most of the time in Firefox, but works every time in Chrome and IE 8+
    title: SI.ServerConfig.get('testTitle')
});
```

But when we access the singleton in the config object in class definition, the **server config singleton is not instantiated in Firefox** all the time. In **Chrome** and in **Internet Explorer 8+** it is **working** as expected.

So to be shure we have the singleton ready to use we tried the following. We moved the Application definition in the callback of an Ext.require. But this does not fix it for Firefox.

```
Ext.require([
    'SI.ServerConfig'
], function () {
    Ext.define('SI.Application', {
      // ....
    }); /
});
```

In the Firefox Debugger the following is logged:

```
Synchrone XMLHttpRequests am Haupt-Thread sollte nicht mehr verwendet werden, 
weil es nachteilige Effekte für das Erlebnis der Endbenutzer hat.
Für weitere Hilfe siehe http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/
```

From the [XHR spezification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#synchronous-flag):

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest outside of workers is in the process of being 
removed from the web platform as it has detrimental effects to the end 
user's experience. (This is a long process that takes many years.) 

Developers must not pass false for the async argument when the JavaScript 
global environment is a document environment. User agents are strongly 
encouraged to warn about such usage in developer tools and may experiment with 
throwing anInvalidAccessError exception when it occurs.
```

So synchrone requests will be removed in the future and only allowed in webworkers.
We need a solution for this.

The **problem** only occurs **in developer mode**, when we build it with **sencha app build**, it **works in Firefox**...

Thanks for any suggestions.
And-y

### Update index.html -> index.php

I changed index.html into index.php like @colinramsay suggested and included the server config object before microloader is included.
Now the warning about `Synchrone XMLHttpRequests` is gone in Firefox.

But the problem when accessing the singleton in the config object in class definition still remains for the Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another totally different approach is to change your application's root index.html to an index.php that does something like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="">
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var SI = {};
        <?php
        echo 'SI.ServerConfig = { "testTitle": "some string" }'; 
        ?>
    </script>

    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

This allows you to change your get code to something like:

```
function get(optionName, defaultVal) {
    if (Ext.isDefined(SI.ServerConfig[optionName])){
        return SI.ServerConfig[optionName];
    }

    return defaultVal;
}
```

You are using PHP to directly output your configuration to the HTML page as JSON before Ext JS and your application load.

Comment: Thank you for this approach, I will try it if this works for our project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Ext.define('SI.view.TestView', {
    extends: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires: ['SI.ServerConfig'],

    constructor: function() {
        this.callParent();
        this.setTitle(SI.ServerConfig.get('testTitle'));
    }
});
```

I suspect this is a load order issue. In your original code, Ext.define would run at the same time SI.ServerConfig, before the requires kicks in, so SI.ServerConfig might not have loaded via requires. By calling it in the constructor you can be sure that all of the requires have been fulfilled and so it should be available.

Comment: Yes we thought about this, but when we have components with lots of items and these items need also some values from the serverConfig, it is hard to adapt this code. Also when the synchronous flag in xhr is removed we will have the same problem, because we need first the data in the serverConfig singelton and then we can access them with the gettter/setter function.